# Pressing tab doesn't expand autocompleted chat @names in Opera

Tags: bug, chat, autocomplete, opera

When using chat, if I start typing someone's name preceded by an `@` I see the autocomplete suggestions pop up above the input box as I would expect, but pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> shifts focus from the text box to the "Send" button instead of expanding the name. I have to either type the name out in its entirety or click on the autocomplete suggestion to get it to expand, which is much slower. This only appears to be happening in Opera (latest stable); Chrome works as expected.

Answer (score 3):

Oh, Opera...Chat special cases Opera when binding the handler used to catch the tab key because historically Opera would not allow a <kbd>tab</kbd> to be cancelled on `keydown`, so `keypress` had to be used instead.

Now, Opera apparently doesn't even *fire* the `keypress` event in the input field because it switches focus to the button on `keydown`. On the flip side, cancelling the tab key in `keydown` now seems to work correctly in Opera, so chat could stop special-casing the handler binding...the only downside being that I don't see a particularly clean way to support both the current and historic behaviours, so Opera users who haven't upgraded recently would likely be out of luck.

Incidentally it looks like this was already done for the comment tab completer on the full site, although someone missed the change in the `unbind`:

```
j && j.unbind($.browser.opera ? "keypress" : "keydown", e).unbind("keyup click", h);
```

Comment: Why we support this damn "browser" is beyond me

Comment: Yes, expanding usernames in comments works fine as far as I can tell.

Comment: @NickCraver Simply because everyone enjoys random's company, I think (or at least I remember him randomly being an Opera user (no pun intended))

Comment: **Opera** is a fine browser. Except for bowing to allow webkit prefixes. That was shameful.

Comment: @random - when did Opera start making a browser? There's a bug machine they've deployed for years but wasn't aware they entered the browser market.

Comment: Funny, Opera is what I use when I want to hear my fans kick up and down, and by waving my mouse inside the chrome I can even make it sound like a singer lives in my case. A virtual theremin as it were. I'm not sure who thought that theremin's should parse HTML however.

Comment: Opera is just a pile of add-ons and features that other browsers eventually roll in years after the fact like brand new Frankenstein fingers @nic